# Creating RenderPartialViewToString with multiple arguments (model and ViewDataDictionary)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a new function that renders a partial view to string that takes in the view, the model **and also a ViewDataDictionary**. I am currently using the function for rendering partials that only take in a model

```
public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'd like to create a new function that can also render a partial to a string, but will also take a another parameter in (in this case a ViewDataDictionary). When I render the partial I want, i do the following within the cshtml code

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Product/ProductQtyPartialView.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary {{"temp", "1,2"}})
```

In the controller and service methods I'd like to render the partial to a string so I can update the view with an updated partial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, I was able to figure it out

```
   public string RenderPartialViewToStringWithNewData(string viewName, object model, string temp)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;
        ViewData["temp"] = temp;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

It is the same as the RenderPartialViewToString Function above with the added line

```
ViewData["temp"] = temp
```

With this new function, you won't have to alter your view and would call this function like so

```
RenderPartialViewToStringWithNewData("~/Views/Product/ComponentsPartialView.cshtml", currProduct, temp)
```